# Why is smoke getting caught my container

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I tried to set up a thing where smoke (being emitted by a small circle) was coming out of cylinder that I inserted and extruded to make a cup. For some reason, the smoke would not rise until I moved the circle past the opening of the cup.

[image: smoke getting caught]

[EDIT] I've recreated the file in 2.8. Even when I bake it, the problem remains.

[image]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the domain settings? make sure your cylinder isnt set to collision. But we really dont have enough info with what you provided. Make sure you baked it, make sure you have the density high enough, Make sure the normal of your small circle is not facing the wrong way. Could be many things.

Comment: I stuck with all the default settings of 2.79b. The cylinder is set to collision, because I thought that was what I wanted for an object to physically interact with the smoke. I have not baked it yet.